# PHP: trying to hide image if session is not started

Tags: php, image, session, hide

I have a script **picture.php** that contains this code

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['pic']) && isset($_SESSION))
{
    $img = imageCreateFromPng($_GET['pic']);
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagePng($img); 
    imagedestroy($img);
}

else
{
    echo 'hidden';
    die;
}
?>
```

I'm trying to hide the image generated from **picture.php** when session is not started.
I have other page named **show.php** which contains a code

```
<?php
    session_start();

    echo '<img src="picture.php?pic=apple.png" />' ;
?>
```

The problem is the image won't show in **show.php** even the **session** is **started** in **show.php** why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to check some session variable then dont forget to start session on top

Try:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_GET['pic']) && empty($_SESSION))
{

    echo 'hidden';
    die;
}

else
{
    $img = imageCreateFromPng($_GET['pic']);
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagePng($img); 
    imagedestroy($img);  
}
?>
```

may this help... `start_session();`

Comment: no no no it generates the image using **picture.php?pic=apple.png** what I'm trying to do is on **show.php** it gonna generrate the image but accession the url **picture.php?pic=apple.png** will not show the image it must be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You actually might want to "flag" if the session is considered started.

picture.php:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['pic']) && isset($_SESSION['initialized']))
{
    unset($_SESSION['initialized']);
    $img = imageCreateFromPng($_GET['pic']);
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagePng($img); 
    imagedestroy($img);
}
else
{
    echo 'hidden';
    die;
}
```

show.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['initialized'] = true;

echo '<img src="picture.php?pic=apple.png" />' ;
```